# Why is pagemtimes in MATLAB slow on GPU?

Tags: matlab, gpu

I'm running my MATLAB code on my GPU (GTX 1060 Q-Max) and I'm having trouble with the execution time of pagemtimes and cross functions. The size of one of the matrices I'm working with (BBI1) is 2 x 2 x 418824 and the other ones are in similar sizes, so using GPU computing should be fine. I'm seeing significant performance loss in the following part of my code:

```
BBI1 = pagemtimes(pagemtimes(xiII_T,xiII),II) - pagemtimes(xiII,xiII_T);
    
BBJ1 = 2*pagemtimes(xiI,xiII_T) - pagemtimes(pagemtimes(xiI_T,xiII),II) - pagemtimes(xiII,xiI_T);
    
eInII = pagemtimes(pagemtimes(xiII_T,xiII),xiI) - pagemtimes(pagemtimes(xiI_T,xiII),xiII);
    
eIInI = pagemtimes(pagemtimes(xiI_T,xiI),xiII) - pagemtimes(pagemtimes(xiII_T,xiI),xiI);

outI = 2 * CC * ((1./AA) - (1./aa)) .* BBI1 + 2 * CC * 1./(aa.^3) .* pagemtimes(eInII,pagetranspose(eInII));
outJ = 2 * CC * ((1./AA) - (1./aa)) .* BBJ1 + 2 * CC * 1./(aa.^3) .* pagemtimes(eInII,pagetranspose(eIInI));
```

Performance test below:

[image]

Are pagemtimes and cross simply not optimized for my case or am I missing something? How can one accelerate the code above?

Update: A minimal reproducible example below:

```
matrix = rand(2,2,418824);
matrix_T = pagetranspose(matrix);

% measure on CPU
tic
times1 = pagemtimes(pagemtimes(matrix,matrix_T),matrix);
toc

% measure on GPU

matrix = gpuArray(matrix);
matrix_T = pagetranspose(matrix);
tic
times2 = pagemtimes(pagemtimes(matrix,matrix_T),matrix);
wait(gpuDevice);
toc
```

Gives the output:

```
Elapsed time is 0.012834 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.440265 seconds.
```

Comment: can you post a [mcve]

Comment: @CrisLuengo The execution time of the code is much slower on GPU than CPU. Kindly see the example in the updated post.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/671413-why-is-pagemtimes-slower-on-gpu-than-a-cpu

Comment: @CrisLuengo, using pagefun produces the same result. In fact, pagemtimes uses pagefun to calculate the multiplication anyways.

Comment: Mert, read all the answers. Double vs single precision? Alternate implementation by writing out the 2x2 matrix multiplication?

Comment: I appreciate your help but single precision is not suitable for my code as it's about "converging" to a final result and it needs be precise (I had already seen that forum post and tried it.). As for the alternate implementation, I couldn't see anything relatable to my code in the forum post you provided. My inputs are already as flat as they could be and ready to be passed to pagemtimes. I can't see any other possible implementation of this as it's a pretty straightforward calculation.